# JQuery CreditCard validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Hi I get the following error when I try to validate credit card, it seems to be a straight forward error, the catch is that it occurs even after the jquery.validate.js is included.

for some reason it is unable to find the function, and has broken my code.

did anyone encounter a similar problem?

(jQuery.validator.methods.creditcard(element.value, element)) is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double triple quadruple check that the javascript is included. And give us the source of the page that is erroring so we can help you debug it.